# Is there a way to write to .ods files from Command line?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

It is too RAM-expensive to keep Libre-Office calc open all the time. And I find it a hassle to open calc everytime I have to add a few lines to my spreadsheet. Is there a way I could do it very minimally, by say opening the terminal and writing into my .ods files? I would like to add rows like these:

```
  A        B     C
1 03/02/16 09:00 Cooking
2 02/07/15 $225  New Clothes
```

I know I can write into .csv format. But I need my formulas. I could make the .ods file read from .csv file into which I write. But then I have to make too many changes to the .ods file.

Comment: I suggest you make a small spreadsheet. Save it. Then, in a file manager (or on your desktop), right-click on the file and choose open with Archive Manager (or something equivalent). Open `content.xml` with a simple text editor and you'll see just how complex the file is. Maybe you could look at a terminal-based spreadsheet application such as `sc` (available in the standard repos).

Comment: For alternatives see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115548/terminal-based-spreadsheets-and-wordprocessor and http://xmodulo.com/make-spreadsheets-linux-terminal.html

Answer (score 0):

`.ods` files are binary so you can't use a text editor as you'd like.  There is another possibility you might consider, but it is not free (albeit fairly cheap).

If you get `insync`, it can sync a folder with google drive.  One of it's very nice features is it can convert .ods files to-and-from Google spreadsheets.

I do this currently.  When I want to run calc locally, I do that.  When I want to make a quick tweak or am on the road, I use Google to make the edit.

I'm not sure what etiquete here is for posting product links, so if you google for "insync google drive" you can find it.

Comment: OP doesn't want to use LibreOffice Calc because it's "RAM-expensive". Will Google Docs be less "RAM-expensive"?

Comment: It should be.  Back when there was a 'Netbook' edition of Ubuntu, they switched to Google Docs by default for the smaller footprint.  On top of that, if you are already running a browser anyway, the relative additional overhead is even smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Run a macro from the command line: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7295/how-to-invoke-an-openoffice-macro-from-the-linux-command-line

Or, unzip the .ods file and make changes to the XML using a text editor.

There are also libraries available such as http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/ which may help.